# Sending files (ANY FORMAT) from GCP to another server without downloading locally?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I am working on a script that takes files from a gcp bucket and uploads them to another server.

Currently my script downloads all of the files from the gcp bucket into my local storage using blob.download_to_filename and then sends a POST request (using requests library) to upload those files to my server.

I know that it is possible to download the files as a string and then re-construct the file. But what about for files that, for example, have pictures? This bucket could fill up with any type of file format and I need to make sure all files will be uploaded exactly how they look in GCP to my server.

Is there some way to temporarily store a file so that I can send it from GCP to my server without having to download it to my computer?

Looking for a way to refer to the file in the POST request that will let me upload it to my server without it being on my local storage?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Run the `gcloud` command (or write a program) on your server to pull the objects from your GCP bucket?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not support pushing files to another system. Instead, write software that runs on the other system that pulls (reads) files from Cloud Storage. However, your question does not have enough details on what the other system is.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some code that:

- Authenticates your request(s) to GCS
- Downloads the objects (perhaps to memory; perhaps in chunks)
- optionally: Authenticates your request to your destination
- Uploads the objects (perhaps in chunks)

You tagged Python and you can do this using Google's Python library for GCS. See [Streaming downloads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-download-object-python) and the recommendation to use [ChunkedDownloads](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-resumable-media/latest/resumable_media/requests.html#chunked-downloads).

With `ChunkedDownloads`, you'd:

- Authenticate using the library
- Iterate over the GCS bucket's content
- Download the objects (files) in chunks (you decide the chunk size) to memory
- Preferably upload/stream the chunks to your destination

It's very likely that there are utilities that support migrating from GCS to your preferred destination.

I'm unfamiliar with any of these and encourage you to validate any options before proceeding to ensure it doesn't steal your credentials.